# Parentheses and pointers node

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures

What is the difference between

```
cout<<(*head_ptr).data()
```

and

```
cout<<*head_ptr.data()
```

Are they both the same or are they different?

Comment: Parentheses should scream [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Operator precedence. see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: `(*head_ptr).data()` is equivalent to `head_ptr->data()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different.

`cout<<(*head_ptr).data()` does:

1. dereference `head_ptr`
2. call `data()` for it
3. pass it to `cout<<`

`cout<<*head_ptr.data()` does:

1. call `data()` for `head_ptr`
2. dereference it
3. pass it to `cout<<`

Comment: Importantly, since the name is `head_ptr`, it's almost certainly a pointer, which has no methods that can be called with `.` syntax, so it's probably not going to compile at all.

Comment: ah okay thank you. Im teaching myself c++ so i was a bit confused. So basically its like in math when using parentheses. So the parentheses are necessary for the first one because it has a higher precedence. And if the second one was to be complied an error would occur right?? because it would trying to activate `head_ptr.data()` before dereferencing it.

Comment: `head_ptr` can be a class (maybe the class play a role of "pointer"), then `head_ptr.data()` can be valid and if it returns a pointer, `*head_ptr.data()` is also valid (if the returned pointer is valid).

Answer (score 0):

The underlying concept is how operators are prioritize. See operator precedence here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence